# The "onchange" event does not work with "value" change in "text input" object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript `input` object with `type="text"` coming along with an `onchange` event which is created by (related lines):

```
var id_box = document.createElement('input');
id_box.id = 'id_box';
id_box.type = 'text';
id_box.onchange = function()
{
    alert("Changed!");
}
```

For changing this `value` in this `input` field I use:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.innerHTML = "A";
a.onclick = function()
{
    document.getElementById('id_box').value = 'A';
}
```

The `onchange` event works only changing value by keyboard typing but not for changing value by above function. Is there any way to make this works?

Please take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/zCMdV/7/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What browser are you using?

I have made this example, which works for me... the subtle change is that I add the event to the input before I append it to the div element.

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id_box = document.createElement('input');
    id_box.type = 'text';
    id_box.onchange = function()
    {
        alert("Changed!");
    }
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(id_box);

</script>
```

See it in action on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/zCMdV/

**Update:**

If you are going to automate the changing of the value, you can do the same to trigger the change event...

http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/zCMdV/10/

```
document.getElementById('id_box').onchange();
```

Comment: I just found that it's not the code problem but the way to change the `value` in `input` field. Please read my question again.

Comment: I'd suggest you remove the non-answer part of your answer, as it threw me off, and could very well be throwing others off..