# Onchange isn't working but the javascript script is fine

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ppid() {
    var ppidtxt = document.getElementById('ppid').value;
    var newppidtxt = ppidtxt.toUpperCase();
    var ppide = document.getElementById('ppid');
    ppide.value = newppidtxt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <center><input type="text" id="ppid" class="form-control" name="ppid" placeholder="Personal Project ID" onchange="ppid();" /></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried  this is JSFiddle, on my local PC, pretty much everywhere but for some reason, whenever I type something in the form's text box with the id "ppid" it isn't capitalizing it. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need just CSS actually: `#ppid { text-transform: capitalize; }`

Comment: @MelanciaUK The real problem is the fact that onchange NEVER works for me, That's what i need a fix for, It's not really the upper-casing part that i need help with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: "onchange" event does not work with "value" change in "text input" object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826707/javascript-onchange-event-does-not-work-with-value-change-in-text-input-o)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using onkeyup instead, e.g.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" />
```

Comment: This worked. You're definitely a JavaScript life-saver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens, but when onchange is called, 'ppid' contains the HTMLInputElement (probably because of its id).

If you rename the function to something unique (like 'myFunc') it works.

@MelanciaUK brought the answer with this link: [Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id

Comment: I wouldn't know about this if I didn't spot this question. Never been through this kind of issue.