# programatically changing value in input field perform some task

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<input id="testinput" type="text"></input>
```

JS

```
$('#testinput').change(function (){
    change();
});
function change(){
    alert();
}
$('#testinput').val('new val');
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ybj1zjhk/)
By typing in input and losing focus it works, but if a change of the input field is triggered by `jquery`, it does not work.
<del>$('#testinput').val('new val').trigger('change');</del> not required.

Comment: $(elem).val('text') doesn't trigger a change. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquer

Comment: If you change teh value programatically the change event won't be triggered, So I guess you no choice but to use `tigger`

Comment: I'm not sure why you've crossed out the `tigger()` version of the code - as that is the best solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: "onchange" event does not work with "value" change in "text input" object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826707/javascript-onchange-event-does-not-work-with-value-change-in-text-input-o)

Comment: I can not change the existing code. values in input change dynamically and on change in input i want to perform some action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) (bolded by me):

> The change event is fired for input, select, and textarea
>   elements **when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user**. Unlike the input event, **the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value**.

You will need to manually trigger the `change` event if you are changing the value programmatically.

I suppose if you are hellbent on not manually firing the change event, you could override jQuery's `val` (`$.fn.val`) method to do it for you:

```
var originalVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function() {
    if(arguments.length) {
       originalVal.apply(this, arguments);
       this.trigger('change');
       return this;
    }
    return originalVal.call(this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybj1zjhk/4/

Answer (score 0):

will fire the alert whenever you type something

```
 $('#testinput').keyup(function (){
        change();
    });
    function change(){
        alert();
    }
    $('#testinput').val('new val');
```

Or you can trigger the change event whenever you do something that requires you to have the change event fire https://jsfiddle.net/owoemcg2/

```
$('#testinput').change(function (){
    change();
});
function change(){
    alert();
}
$("#mybutton").click(function(){

$('#testinput').val('new val');  
$("#testinput").trigger("change");
});
```