# javascript pass variable to text input onchange event not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fill a text input using a URL parameter: `http://127.0.0.1/index.html?uname="john"`

```
<p class="control">
<input autofocus id="uname" class="input" 
  onchange="(sayhello(this.value))" 
  oninput="sayhello(this.value)" 
  placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
</p>
```

I use the following script to pass the URL parameter into text input but the events don't work, they works only if I delete the input text and type it.

```
<script>
var uunme = window.location.href.match(/\?uname=(.*)/);
document.getElementById("uname").value = uunme[1];

</script>
```

Comment: `sayhello` is not a native function. Also, change/input events are not triggered when changing the value of an input programmatically. You've to manually call the event handler, or fire the change/input event.

Comment: Neither `onchange` nor `oninput` will trigger when you set the value programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826707/javascript-onchange-event-does-not-work-with-value-change-in-text-input-o

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this?**

```js
var url_string = "https://example.com/?uname=foo"; // window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var uunme = url.searchParams.get("uname");
document.getElementById("uname").value = uunme;

function sayhello(text) {
  alert(text);
}
```

```html
<p class="control">
  <input autofocus id="uname" class="input" onchange="sayhello(this.value);" oninput="sayhello(this.value);" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
</p>
```

I used the answer from the Stackoverflow question "[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975)" to reliably retrieve the URL parameter `uname`. I also tidied up a few things.

Comment: i know that, when the page loads the parametr foo is loaded in input text but the function doesnt work

Comment: The `sayhello()` function?

Comment: yes, only works if i delete the input text, and type it manual

Comment: In my example it's working. Can you maybe provide the code in your `sayhello()` function?

Comment: i use the same with your, when you run your code the function works ?? for me only work when i type something into input text

Comment: Yeah when you press `Run code snippet`, nothing happens until you start typing in the input box. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: no, this is the problem, i need the function hello works when the url load

Comment: In your javascript code, why can't you just call the function instantly with `sayhello(uunme);`?

Comment: sure that works, but first had to fill the parametr in text input

Comment: then just run `sayhello(uunme);` after you fill the parametr in text input.